# Serve RSS feed with different languages for different items

Tags: rss

Is it possible to create an RSS (2.0) feed with multiple languages? Say I blog mainly in English (`en`), but sometimes I create German (`de`) posts.

Is there support for this in the RSS spec? I couldn't find anything in the [RSS spec](http://www.rssboard.org/rss-specification) on this issue.

There doesn't seem to be a language sub-element below item and I'm not sure if it's valid to put multiple language codes separated by comma in the language element of channel.

Actually I don't care too much about setting the language for specific items in the feed, but rather I'd like to specify a *primary language* and a *secondary language*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The specific RSS `<language>` element is only valid at the top level and specifies:

> The language the channel is written in.

Atom uses the more general [`xml:lang` attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#sec-lang-tag) and makes clear that in can be used [on any element](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4287#section-2):

> Any element defined by this specification MAY have an xml:lang
> attribute, whose content indicates the natural language for the
> element and its descendents.

It would be acceptable to use `xml:lang` on specific items in an RSS feed. However, with RSS or Atom, your decision will largely be affected by whether clients pay attention to it.

Comment: What if, with RSS, the channel is written in two languages?

Comment: RSS has no way to express that, unfortunately. You would have to mark the second-language items with `xml:lang` and hope that clients picked that up.

Comment: OK, so with I'd specify `xml:lang="en"` on the `<feed>` element for the primary language, and on any `<entry>` element which content is a different language I'd specify `xml:lang="…"`